# Run calculations on specific columns in a dataframe by looping

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, subset

Here is an example of the data:

```
  Test.Statistic          P     FDR_P Bonferroni_P Control_mean NH4._mean
1       8.203199 0.01654619 0.7405529            1         0.00  0.000000
2       7.622793 0.02211727 0.7405529            1         0.00  1.095238
3       7.501205 0.02350357 0.7405529            1         2.10  1.761905
4       6.510000 0.03858082 0.7405529            1         0.85  0.000000
5       6.149339 0.04620490 0.7405529            1         0.65  5.095238
6       6.052381 0.04850005 0.7405529            1         0.00  1.428571
  NO3._mean
1 0.4285714
2 1.1904762
3 1.1428571
4 0.0000000
5 3.4285714
6 0.0000000
```

I want to apply the formula (trt_mean/control_mean)-1 to each treatment column (NH4 and NO3). I incorporated some comments but am still having trouble calling column 1 (control_mean) in dt.

```
dt <- as.data.frame.table(kw_res)
cols <- grep("_mean", colnames(dt))
rel_abund_function <- function(z) {
  return((z / z[, 1])-1)
}

dt[, lapply(cols, rel_abund_function)]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post some example data?

Comment: please provide a reproducible example for us to use and post expected output for said example. you can use `dput(head(df))` to display some of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)
colnames(dt) <- c(sapply(1:5, function(z) paste("ctrl",z,sep="")),
                  sapply(1:5, function(z) paste("treatment",z,"_mean", sep="")), 
                  "rawval")
```

**DATA**

```
> head(dt)
   ctrl1 ctrl2 ctrl3 ctrl4 ctrl5 treatment1_mean treatment2_mean treatment3_mean treatment4_mean treatment5_mean rawval
1:  21.0     6   160   110  3.90           2.620           16.46               0               1               4      4
2:  21.0     6   160   110  3.90           2.875           17.02               0               1               4      4
3:  22.8     4   108    93  3.85           2.320           18.61               1               1               4      1
4:  21.4     6   258   110  3.08           3.215           19.44               1               0               3      1
5:  18.7     8   360   175  3.15           3.440           17.02               0               0               3      2
6:  18.1     6   225   105  2.76           3.460           20.22               1               0               3      1
```

**CODE**

get the columns that have a specific name format (`_mean`) in this example, and apply a custom function:

```
cols <- grep("_mean", colnames(dt))
my_mean_func <- function(z){
  return((z-mean(z))/100)
}

dt[, lapply(.SD, my_mean_func), .SDcols = cols]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> head(dt[, lapply(.SD, my_mean_func), .SDcols = cols])
   treatment1_mean treatment2_mean treatment3_mean treatment4_mean treatment5_mean
1:      -0.0059725      -0.0138875       -0.004375       0.0059375        0.003125
2:      -0.0034225      -0.0082875       -0.004375       0.0059375        0.003125
3:      -0.0089725       0.0076125        0.005625       0.0059375        0.003125
4:      -0.0000225       0.0159125        0.005625      -0.0040625       -0.006875
5:       0.0022275      -0.0082875       -0.004375      -0.0040625       -0.006875
6:       0.0024275       0.0237125        0.005625      -0.0040625       -0.006875
```

Comment: I think I am on the right track, can you help me resolve issue calling the control_mean column?

Comment: @Becca I can try to help but can you provide a proper example of what you see and what you want as the output? It's not very clear at the moment. Also, please use `dput(data_frame_name)` for the raw data - makes it easier to read into R. For the output, if you want to paste it, that's okay.